# Unable to generate initialization code within Repeater

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

**Problem:**

Following error is arising if I use NavigatorContent in Repeater. Is there a way to initialize image and lable on which I am encountering following error:

> Unable to generate initialization code
>   within Repeater, due to id or data
>   binding on a component that is not a
>   visual child.

**Code:**

```
<mx:Repeater id="rep" dataProvider="{usersArray}">
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="{rep.currentItem.name}" >
            <mx:Image x="10" y="10" source="{rep.currentItem.imagePath}" width="175" height="118"/>
            <s:Label x="145" y="14" text="{rep.currentItem.name}"/>
            <s:Button x="147" y="79" label="Edit User" width="79" height="22" click="currentState='AddUser'"/>
            <s:Button x="231" y="79" label="Delete" width="56" height="22"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The NavigatorContent class defines a
>   Spark container that can be used in an
>   MX navigator container, such as the
>   ViewStack, TabNavigator and Accordion
>   containers.
>
> Do not use a NavigatorContent
>   container outside of an MX navigator
>   container.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/NavigatorContent.html

I guess you would want to use a Canvas or a custom component in the Repeater. Or you could use the DataGroup instead of the Repeater.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGroup.html